# Is there a way to use ubuntu one for synchronizing Thunderbird on 2 computers?

Tags: ubuntu-one, thunderbird

Actually, I don't find a way to synchronize **thunderbird on 2 computers**. It is really sad but there is no easy way to manage it ... no add-ons or sync options such as on Firefox.
I was wondering if it could be possible to use **Ubuntu one** for this. 
I thank you all in advance for your help. 
Regards

Comment: Based on your comment below I think you should restore your backup .Thunderbird directory to both computers, then use IMAP like @bkzland suggested. IMAP will keep future changes in sync, the backup you have can just be moved to each computer so you have the same starting point. U1 would add unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Is your email folder under your profile folder?

Answer (score 1):

You could store your whole profile folder in a shared folder that is synched with ubuntu one and place a symlink in the old location so thunderbird picks it up.

Your profiles are stored in `~/.mozilla-thunderbird/<Profile name>`, so

1. open a shell and move it to the shared folder with `mv ~/.mozilla-thunderbird/<Profile name> <sharedfolder>/`
2. create a symlink using `ln -s '<sharedfolder>/<Profile name>' ~/.mozilla-thunderbird/<Profile name>`
3. repeat step 2 for the synchronized computer.

If you're only interested in synching the emails, not the addons and settings of your mailclient, you should just switch your account type to IMAP.

Comment: Well, it's not only moving a thunderbird profile, but in the meantime all the mails and data stored on my current thunderbird profile. You see what I mean ?
I already have thousands mail saved and I would like to have them on several computers, they are already deleted on mail accounts, only available on my thunderbird.

Comment: -The trouble is still not solved, but - In the meantime, I was wondering if everyone know any add-ons on thunderbird that could make it instead of using Ubuntu-one ?

Comment: It sounds to me like you want IMAP type accounts for your emails, this will always keep your clients up to date with the server. The mailserver you are using needs to support this. Once you set it up, you can easily add your local mails to your IMAP account, given that it has enough space (eg. googlemail has plenty). You can follow the steps outlined here http://kb.mozillazine.org/IMAP:_advanced_account_configuration but thunderbird will guide you through it if you set up a mail account for an ISP that it knows (googlemail is configured by default as IMAP through thunderbird).